# Regex - certain string inside quotes

Tags: python, regex, talend

I am looking for regex to replace double tilde but only inside the single quotation mark to improve performance of my script. Let's say I have String like this:

```
(10070177,4,72,0,819391,'(OP~~SC~~OC~~OV)'~~10070178,4,72,0,819392,'(OP~~SC~~OC~~OV)')
```

and I want to match ~~ between OP and SC, SC an OC etc. so only those between '. Note that I need to match double tilde not all / any text.

My Scripting language here is Python

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> s="(10070177,4,72,0,819391,'(OP~~SC~~OC~~OV)'~~10070178,4,72,0,819392,'(OP~~SC~~OC~~OV)')"
```

You can capture the entire group with `'` quotes around it and replace the `~` only on that substring:

```
>>> re.sub(r"('[^']+')",lambda m: m.group(0).replace('~','!'), s)
(10070177,4,72,0,819391,'(OP!!SC!!OC!!OV)'~~10070178,4,72,0,819392,'(OP!!SC!!OC!!OV)')
```

That is easier (and more robust and faster) than a more complex regex to do the same thing.

Comment: it works pretty good (surprisingly better than parsing each line char by char) but it messes things up when there's nothing inside quotes. for example:
`(4868182,4,72,0,510376,''),(4868182,4,72,0,510376,'(OP~~SC~~OC~~OV)')`

Comment: You did not state that as a requirement, but you can use `*` instead of `+` after the character class: `r"('[^']*')",...` or replace empty quotes with quotes with a space inside: `re.sub(r"('[^']+')",lambda m: m.group(0).replace('~','!'), s.replace("''","' '")`